# How does this step imply the next in this proof of the weak law of large numbers?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-limit-theorems

"Suppose . $ X_1, X_2,...$ is a sequence of independent and identically distributed random variables with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma^2$.
Then for any $\epsilon \gt 0$,

$$\overline{X}_n \to \mu, \space \text{as}\space n \to \infty$$
where "$\to$" in this context is used to mean "converges in probability to "

Proof:
Apply Chebyshev's inequality to $\overline{X}_n$, which has mean $\mu$ and variance $\frac{\sigma^2}{n}$:

So for $r \gt 0$, ($r \in \mathbb{R}$),

$P(|\overline{X}_n - \mu|\geq \frac{r\sigma}{\sqrt{n}})\leq \frac{1}{r^2}$

$\Leftarrow\Rightarrow \space 1 -P(|\overline{X}_n - \mu|\lt \frac{r\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}) \leq \frac{1}{r^2}$

$\Leftarrow\Rightarrow \space 1 -P(|\overline{X}_n - \mu|\lt \frac{r\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}) \leq \frac{1}{r^2}$

$\Leftarrow\Rightarrow \space P(|\overline{X}_n - \mu|\lt \frac{r\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}) \geq 1-\frac{1}{r^2}$

**"It follows that, given $\delta \gt 0$, if $n> \frac{\sigma^2}{\delta\epsilon^2}$ then 
$1\geq P(|\overline{X}_n - \mu|\lt \epsilon) \gt 1 - \delta$
thus proving the result."**

My question is to do with the last line:

what exactly is happening is here?

How does this prove the result?

(It looks a bit like a limit proof with an n, $\epsilon$ and $\delta$, where it seems that the author is finding an N such that for all n $\overline{X}_n$ tends to $\mu$...)

Answer (score 1):

Alright, so this is my best shot so far.  Recall the definition of convergence in probability:

$$\forall \epsilon>0, \underset{n \rightarrow \infty}{lim}P(|\overline{X}_n - X|< \epsilon) = 1$$

Also note the fact you presented above. With this fact we can see for some fixed $\delta>0$, where $n > \frac{\sigma^2}{\delta \epsilon^2}$.

$$ P \left (|\overline{X}_n - X|< \frac{r \sigma}{\sqrt{n}} \right ) < P \left (|\overline{X}_n - X|<\frac{r\sigma}{\sqrt{\frac{\sigma^2}{\delta \epsilon^2}}} \right )=P \left (|\overline{X}_n - X|< r\sqrt{\delta} \epsilon \right )  $$

Since $\delta$ and $r$ are arbitrary and fixed. We can say let $\delta  = \frac{1}{r^2}$.  Then, because of Chebyshev's inequality, we have

$$1- \frac{1}{\epsilon^2} \leq P \left (|\overline{X}_n - X|< \epsilon \right )  \leq 1$$

Which is equivalent to,

$$1 \geq P \left (|\overline{X}_n - X|< \epsilon \right )  \geq 1- \frac{1}{\epsilon^2}$$

Now $\epsilon$ is just any positive real number.  So we can always rewrite $1/\sqrt{\epsilon_0} = \epsilon$ and get,

$$1 \geq P \left (|\overline{X}_n - X|< 1/\sqrt{\epsilon_0} \right )  \geq 1- \epsilon_0$$.

I am not sure if this is what you had in mind.  Let me know if I there is an assumption in your prompt. Note that there are other ways to proof WLLN which I think are easier in the long run.